# Dropdown select string font style change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this dropdown filter that is generated from a DB. It gives the selection list for users to select from.

This is the sample product list.

```
-View All-
-iPhone-
-Android-
-WindowsPhone-
-Blackberry-
```

However, I want to make the 'iPhone' string to bold face in this script code.
Please advice kindly?

```
var dropdown= function( response ){
    var productFilter = $('.dropdownControl');

    productFilter .change( userMgmtFilterDDChange );
    var pdlist= response.Results.Products;

    var dropdownString = '';
    dropdownString += '<option selected="selected">View All</option>';
    $.each( pdlist, function( index, item ){
        dropdownString += '<option>' + item.Name + '</option>';
    });
    productFilter .append( dropdownString );
}
```

Comment: Do you want the string iPhone to be bold or only the second element from the dropdown ?

Comment: the iPhone string to be bolded. Thanks!

Comment: There is no cross browser way for styling select options, unless you use a plugin that alters the default controls. Tested [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uX2vX/) and found that only firefox accepts CSS styling with a class

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I think it works fine in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class in jQuery if the name is iPhone, that way :

```
   $.each( pdlist, function( index, item ){
    if (item.Name == 'iPhone'){
      dropdownString += '<option class="bold">' . item.Name . '</option>';
    }
    else{
      dropdownString += '<option>' + item.Name + '</option>';
    }
 });
```

Then, in your css file, use this

```
   .bold{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: Note that I've suggested the class name bold, but you're better using a more significative class name if possible, such as iPhone or hype-product, something that you may re-use later or that, at least, describe the use you make of that class on your website !

Answer (score 0):

Change  this

```
 dropdownString += '<option>' + item.Name + '</option>';
```

To that

```
dropdownString += '<option>' + (item.Name==Iphone ?'<b>'+item.name+'</b>': item.name) + '</option>';
```

Comment: It's better to use a class because you might want to change the style of it later, in addition, it's better not to use b tag no more for schementic reason, it doesn't makes sense

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags

Comment: My pleasure! I'd suggest using <strong> tag for important words of your websites, good for schementic and SEO, plus, it makes more sense than bold and by default, it makes your element bold